# how is the tooltip added to JButton

Tags: java, swing

I did not understand the first line of the below code could you please explain it

```
JButton b1 = new JButton("Hello, World") {
public JToolTip createToolTip() {
     JToolTip tip = super.createToolTip();
     tip.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
     tip.setForeground(Color.RED);
     return tip;
  } 
};
```

Comment: `b1.setToolTipText("your tooltip");`
Welcome to stackoverflow! Please research these things before asking a question.

Comment: @DCON it is not b1.setToolTipText it is new JButton("hello,wolrd"){ public JtoolTip createToolTip(){..... i am talking about my code i did not understand the first and second line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code creates a new instance of a JButton with an overwritten `createToolTip()` method. This method is normally defined in `JComponent` class, what is a super class of `JButton`.

With calling `super.createToolTip()` this method from `JComponent` is called first, but then the foreground and background color of the tool tip are changed to something that is specific to your `JButton` instance.

Another way to do it would be to create a new class `MyNewButtonWithSpecialToolTip` that extends `JButton` and overwrites only the `createToolTip()` method. But this would require more code and an additional class file what is not required when you have only one button with this special functionality.

Comment: Thanks it was  helpful